# ODBC - Insert value list does not match column list

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I'm using prepared statements to insert a row into a table, but I get returned this error from the PHP log. Please note that I redacted the filepath.

> [20-Apr-2015 13:15:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  `odbc_execute()`: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Insert value list does not match column list, SQL state 21S01 in SQLDescribeParameter in `foobar.php` on line 93

The table I'm inserting into is set up as such. The column names have been modified to something simple for this example. Types are included.

```
TABLE1
ID  | C1      | C2      | C3       | C4      | C5  | C6      | C7      | C8
int | varchar | varchar | datetime | varchar | int | varchar | varchar | varchar
```

Please note that `ID` increments automatically for each insert. This functionality is behaving as intended. Here is my query. It's simple:

```
$stmt = odbc_prepare($this->connection,"
    INSERT INTO TABLE1 (C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8)
    VALUES (?, ?, CAST(CONVERT(char, GETDATE(), 100) AS datetime), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
");

error_log($c1.' '.$c2.' '.$c4.' '.$c5.' '.$c6.' '.$c7.' '.$c8);

if( odbc_execute($stmt,array($c1,$c2,$c4,$c5,$c6,$c7,$c8)) )
{
    error_log("Success");
}
else
{
    error_log("Failure");
}
odbc_free_result($stmt);
```

When I pass only `C1` to `C6` this works as intended. For example, this query executes successfully. I can leave the `odbc_execute` statement above unmodified for this:

```
$stmt = odbc_prepare($this->connection,"
    INSERT INTO TABLE1 (C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8)
    VALUES (?, ?, CAST(CONVERT(char, GETDATE(), 100) AS datetime), ?, ?, ?, '?', '?')
");
```

This will insert the string `?` into `C7` and `C8`. I took this method simply for debug purposes, and that's as far as I was able to get. The moment I try to insert `C7` and `C8`, the query fails entirely. I looked at the types to ensure that there was matching, and there was. `$c7` and `$c8` are strings, `C7` and `C8` are varchars. I used `error_log` to print the variables right before execution, and the variables held the correct values.

My only remaining theory is that you somehow are unable to insert this many values into the table for some reason, but this does not make sense either. Later on in the code I have much larger inserts that work just fine without this problem. I've never really seen anything like this, so I'm curious if anybody has any leads on what's going on here. I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: have you tried passing all the varchars using quotes as the sql accept it. Also so a try with hardcoded values it helps sometimes.

Comment: @openandfree Hardcoded values give the same result. I can't use quotes for this problem because I'm using prepared statements. Last thing I can try is to just drop the table and start with a fresh one.

Comment: Okay. give me one more chance,  pass the auto increament ID as 0 from query.

Comment: As a test, what happens if you replace 'CAST(CONVERT(char, GETDATE(), 100) AS datetime)' also by a '?' and pass in a value that can be casted to a datetime for the column c3?

Comment: @openandfree Unfortunately, I can't do that. Here's the error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TABLE1' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF., SQL state 23000 in SQLExecute in foobar.php on line 96

Comment: @erg Unfortunately, this too does not work. This is probably one of the most astounding problems I've come across in my life... Sadly I'm also stuck with having to use ODBC, as opposed to PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: @Mari M: Just to be 100% sure: Have you really, really checked twice or three times that in the original query (not the simplified sample) the column names are correct, the number of '?' matches the number of arguments and that there is no forgotten ',' somewhere?
When I looked at the question first I thought: "Easy, probably one parameter got forgotten / there is '?' that should not be or something like this"
I've seen this error quite often, but it was always because I made a stupid mistake or typo in the SQL-query...

Comment: I checked, had others check, went home for a weekend, returned and checked again, then had others check. I really, really wish it was a stupid typo. I'm starting to believe it's a problem with the ODBC driver we have, since if I use prepared statements for C1-C6 and then not for C7-C8 it works. +1 for good advice on checking for simple stupid mistakes, that is a lifesaver technique for many.

Comment: have you tried converting GETDATE to a varchar instead of a char?   Also try including the length component of the varchar conversion.  (eg:   CONVERT(varchar(31),GETDATE(),100)

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but the problem doesn't lie with that field. I think it's a problem with the ODBC driver. This ended up working for me, but I don't think it's a good answer: `VALUES (?,?,CAST(CONVERT(varchar(31), GETDATE(), 100) AS datetime),?,?,?,'$c7','$c8')`